# Export list of installed packages in SublimeText

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am aware that I can see all installed packages in Sublime using `Ctrl+Shift+P` and selecting `Package Control: List Packages`.

I have many packages installed (>20) and I need a way to export their names (and ideally also the link to their https://packagecontrol.io/ page) to a text file or similar output.

Can this be done at all?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can easily get the list of installed packages by looking at Package Control's user preferences file: `Preferences -> Package Settings -> Package Control -> Preferences - User` and checking the `installed_packages` value.

Getting the URL as well is a bit more complicated, but can be done for example by executing the following in ST's Python console (View menu -> Show Console):

```
import os; [(os.path.dirname(file)[len('Packages/'):], sublime.decode_value(sublime.load_resource(file))['url']) for file in sublime.find_resources('package-metadata.json')]
```

Comment: For some reason sublime.decode_value is failing for me in a new installation of Sublime.  If you're just trying to get a list of package names to paste in "advanced install" in a new installation of sublime, you can just eliminate that part of the command and use:

`import os; [(os.path.dirname(file)[len('Packages/'):]) for file in sublime.find_resources('package-metadata.json')]`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer unfortunately didn't work for me. 
Then I found that in Windows 10 (at least for ST 3) you can obtain what you want by listing the files contained in

```
C:\Users\<your_user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages
```

But some installed packages might be missing from this list ! Crosscheck your result with the content of the directory

```
C:\Users\<your_user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages
```